# NullPointer Exception at Boolean value assign

Tags: apex, controller, exception, null-pointer, system

Please find below class where I get Null Pointer Exception while assigning value to boolean. Please let me know where is my fault here? Thanks!

Apex Class:

```
public class CallReplica_controller 
 {

    public CallReplica_controller() {

    }



     public String Ids {get;set;}   
      public String CallId {get;set;}
      public List<Call2_vod__c> CList{get;set;} 
      public List<Call2_vod__c> Accts{get;set;}
      Public Set<Id> Acc;  
      Public Boolean SameSize{get;set;}  
      Public Id leadId {get;set;}

      public CallReplica_controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller)//Constructor
  {  SameSize=false;
  String id =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');//Call id
  CList=[SELECT Account_vod__c, Account_vod__r.Name,Account_Plan_vod__c, Activity_Type__c, Add_Detail_vod__c, Address_vod__c, Address_Line_1_vod__c, Address_Line_2_vod__c, Attendee_Associated_Prescriber_CIA__c, Assignment_Datetime_vod__c, Associated_Prescriber_CIA__c, Allowed_Products_vod__c, Attendee_Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c, Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c, Attendee_Post_Status_vod__c, Attendee_Role_CIA__c, Attendee_Type_vod__c, Attendees_vod__c, Breakthrough_Activity_MHC__c, CIA_Switched_Calls_CIA__c, Business_Account_Name_ABT__c, CLM_vod__c, Number_of_CRNA_abt__c, zvod_Call_Conflict_Status_vod__c, Owner_Full_Name_abv__c, Call_Role_Header_CIA__c, City_vod__c, Color_vod__c, Credentials_vod__c, CreatedDate, CreatedById, Contract_Next_Steps_MHC__c, Contact_vod__c, Call_Date_vod__c, Call_Datetime_vod__c, IsDeleted, Deliver_Any_Day_abv__c, Delivery_Day_abt__c, Delivery_Day_2_abt__c, Delivery_Day_3_abt__c, Delivery_Day_4_abt__c, Disbursed_To_vod__c, Detailed_Products_vod__c, Duration_vod__c, Disclaimer_vod__c, Entity_Display_Name_vod__c, Entity_Reference_Id_vod__c, Error_Reference_Call_vod__c, Expense_Amount_vod__c, Expense_Attendee_Type_vod__c, Expense_Post_Status_vod__c, Expense_System_External_ID_vod__c, Getting_Started_Kits_ABT__c, Formatted_Name__c, Attendee_Affirmation_CIA__c, Affirmation_CIA__c, Incurred_Expense_vod__c, IsLocked, Is_Parent_Call_vod__c, Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c, Interaction_abt__c, License_Status_ABT__c, License_Expiration_Date_vod__c, License_Expiration_Date_ABT__c, License_ABT__c, Location_Services_Status_vod__c, zvod_Business_Account_vod__c, MAX_ID_ABT__c, Number_of_MD_abt__c, MD_Time_abt__c, Medical_Event_vod__c, MayEdit, Next_Steps_Overall_abv__c, Next_Step_Overall_MHC__c, Modified_Call_Reference_HS__c, Mobile_Last_Modified_Datetime_vod__c, OwnerId, Override_Lock_vod__c, Attendee_list_vod__c, Parent_Address_vod__c, Parent_Call_vod__c, Parent_Call_Mobile_ID_vod__c, Number_of_Pharmacy_abt__c, Submit_DateTime_ABT__c, X24_X_7_nurse_phone_support_ABT__c, ASSMCA_vod__c, Add_Key_Message_vod__c, Assigner_vod__c, CRNA_Time_abt__c, Call_Sample_Update__c, Call_Comments_vod__c, Concur_Address_abv__c, Concur_Description_abv__c, DEA_vod__c, DEA_Address_vod__c, DEA_Address_Line_1_vod__c, DEA_Address_Line_2_vod__c, DEA_City_vod__c, DEA_Expiration_Date_vod__c, DEA_State_vod__c, DEA_Zip_vod__c, DEA_Zip_4_vod__c, HPP_DMARD_Benefit_ABT__c, HPP_copay_support_ABT__c, HPP_foundation_support_ABT__c, Insurance_process_support_ABT__c, LastActivityDate, Last_Device_vod__c, Last_Modified_By__c, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, License_vod__c, License_Status_vod__c, Location_vod__c, Medication_reminders_ABT__c, Mobile_Created_Datetime_vod__c, Mobile_ID_vod__c, Next_Call_Notes_vod__c, No_Disbursement_vod__c, Name, Nurse_injection_training_ABT__c, Original_Call_Reference_HS__c, Number_of_Other_HCPs_abt__c, Other_HCP_Time_abt__c, Pharmacy_Time_abt__c, Planning_Time_abt__c, Pre_Call_Notes_vod__c, Presentations_vod__c, Product_Priority_1_vod__c, Product_Priority_2_vod__c, Product_Priority_3_vod__c, Product_Priority_4_vod__c, Product_Priority_5_vod__c, Professional_Abbott_Best_Specialty_ABT__c, Professional_Degree_ABT__c, Professional_First_Name_ABT__c, Professional_Last_Name_ABT__c, Professional_ME_ABT__c, Professional_Middle_Name_ABT__c, Professional_Salutation_ABT__c, Professional_Status_ABT__c, Professional_Type_ABT__c, Property_vod__c, Number_of_RN_cia__c, RN_Time_cia__c, Id, RecordTypeId, Salesforce_ABT__c, Salutation_vod__c, Sample_Card_vod__c, Sample_Card_Reason_vod__c, Sample_Send_Card_vod__c, Sharps_containers_ABT__c, Sharps_mailback_services_ABT__c, Ship_Address_Line_1_vod__c, Ship_Address_Line_2_vod__c, Ship_City_vod__c, Ship_Country_vod__c, Ship_License_vod__c, Ship_License_Expiration_Date_vod__c, Ship_License_Status_vod__c, Ship_State_vod__c, Ship_To_Address_Text_vod__c, Ship_To_Address_vod__c, Ship_Zip_vod__c, Ship_Zip_4_vod__c, Signature_vod__c, Signature_Date_vod__c, Signature_Location_Latitude_vod__c, Signature_Location_Longitude_vod__c, Signature_Page_Image_vod__c, Signature_Timestamp_vod__c, Significant_Event__c, Site_Onboarding_Next_Steps_abv__c, State_vod__c, Status_vod__c, Subject_vod__c, Submitted_By_Mobile_vod__c, Supervising_Physician_vod__c, Supervising_Physician_Credential_vod__c, Supervising_Physician_License_vod__c, Supervising_Physician_Name_vod__c, SystemModstamp, Territory_vod__c, Total_Expense_Attendees_Count_vod__c, Travel_Time_abt__c, Call_Type_vod__c, USHCP_abv__c, Uncovering_Needs_abt__c, Unlock_vod__c, User_vod__c, Zip_vod__c, Zip_4_vod__c, myHUMIRA_Overview_ABT__c, zvod_Account_Call_Reminder_vod_c_vod__c, zvod_Account_Credentials_vod_c_vod__c, zvod_Account_Preferred_Name_vod_c_vod__c, zvod_Address_vod_c_DEA_Status_vod_c_vod__c, zvod_Account_Sample_Status_vod_c_vod__c, zvod_Attachments_vod__c, zvod_Attendees_vod__c, zvod_CLMDetails_vod__c, zvod_Entity_vod__c, zvod_Call_Objective_vod__c, zvod_Delete_vod__c, zvod_Detailing_vod__c, zvod_Expenses_vod__c, zvod_Followup_vod__c, zvod_Key_Messages_vod__c, zvod_More_Actions_vod__c, zvod_Product_Discussion_vod__c, zvod_Samples_vod__c,
  zvod_Save_vod__c, zvod_SaveNew_vod__c, zvod_Submit_vod__c, zvod_Surveys_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where id=:id];

  System.debug('My call-->'+CList);

  if(CList.get(0).Parent_call_vod__c!=null)
  { Accts=[select Account_vod__c,Id from Call2_vod__c where Parent_call_vod__c=:CList.get(0).Parent_call_vod__c];
    For(Call2_vod__c c: Accts)
      { Acc.add(c.Account_vod__c);
       }
       Acc.add(CList.get(0).Account_vod__c);
  }

   List<UserRecordAccess> HasAccessList = [SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId=:UserInfo.getUserId() AND RecordId IN :Acc LIMIT 200];
      If(HasAccessList.size() == Acc.size()) // **This Line throws Error!**
       {SameSize=true;}

      }


   public PageReference getredirectPage(){
      // string leadId = '';
       if(SameSize){
          leadId = CList.get(0).Parent_call_vod__c;

       PageReference send = new PageReference('/' + leadId);
       send.setRedirect(true);
       return send;  

       }

       else return null;   
   }
    }
```

Comment: Please remove as much irrelevant code as possible. If you want us to put work into helping you, put some work into helping us.

Comment: Sorry Adrian. Will surely do do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `Acc`. Place `Acc = new Set<Id>();` in your constructor.

Comment: It throws this Error:-  Compile Error: expecting a left angle bracket, found '(' at line - Acc = new Set();